# Event Reporting

Tags: civievent, civireport

I am trying to create an Event Report using the Event Summary template. What I need is a summary based on the fee level. I see the fee label, but not the fee level. Is there any report out there using this field? If not I see where I can create a custom php and template file. I did create that, but I am having an issue figuring out how/where to add the code to get the fee level. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of extensions you can check out that offer more advanced reporting on fee levels:

Eileen's extended reports:
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport

Line item report extension:
https://civicrm.org/blogs/jproffitt/announcing-the-line-item-report-extension

I hope these are helpful?